# Try/Catch block unexpected behaviour in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Below I register a user after authenticating through FB/Google. The issue here is in the try block. When I throw an error, for example when displayName already taken or user is already registered, the catch block is triggered but it appears to continue executing code in the try block because after throwing the error I am always getting redirected in the browser to '/' (last line of code in try block).

One solution would be to navigate the user programmatically on the client side but I don't see why this existing code doesn't work as expected.

```
  app.post("/auth/register", requireAuth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      if (req.user.registered === true) {
        throw new Error("You have already registered.")
      }
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({
        displayName_lower: req.body.displayName
      });

      if (existingUser) {
        throw new Error("Display name already is use! Try another.");
      }

      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.user.id },
        {
          displayName: req.body.displayName,
          displayName_lower: req.body.displayName,
          registered: true,
          joined: Date.now()
        }
      );

      // Create and save new faves, follows, followers, messageBox doc for every newly reg'd user
      await new Faves({
        _owner: req.user.id
      }).save();
      await new Follows({
        _owner: req.user.id
      }).save();
      await new Followers({
        _owner: req.user.id
      }).save();
      await new MessageBox({
        _owner: req.user.id
      }).save();

      res.redirect("/");
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).send({ error: e.message });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Using try catch in an async function like this is fine. Are you sure the redirect originated from the attached code, and not some other piece of middleware in your express config?

Comment: @JonasH yes Maybe the `requireAuth` middleware is redrecting for OP.

Comment: Yes it does appear to be originating from somewhere else. The requireAuth mw is triggered before and doesn't redirect so I don't think it's the culprit either. I'll keep looking, at least I know the try block is not the issue.

Comment: I resolved the issue. I was already navigating on the client side with react-router after making the request to register. I had forgot to remove it. Thanks to all who answered